ionic/firebase package dependencies incompatibility
can you guys help me figure out how to gradually update these packages, i have no problems in my outdated packages untill i need to install a specific package that needs a certain version of some packages (i hope you understand)
i am quite weak in terms of fixing dependencies as i have limited knowledge about its versions
this is the package and the error i encounter
npm install @capacitor/push-notifications
npm notice
npm notice New major version of npm available! 9.7.1 -> 10.9.1
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.9.1
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@10.9.1 to update!
npm notice
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: NouriNest@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @capacitor/core@5.7.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@capacitor/core
npm ERR!   @capacitor/core@"5.7.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @capacitor/core@"^6.0.0" from @capacitor/push-notifications@6.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@capacitor/push-notifications
npm ERR!   @capacitor/push-notifications@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\SeanPao\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-11-24T15_04_10_194Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\SeanPao\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-11-24T15_04_10_194Z-debug-0.log


and these are my outdated packages i cant update because of incompatibility issues
npm outdated
Package                                 Current   Wanted  Latest  Location                    
                         Depended by
@angular-devkit/build-angular            17.3.1  17.3.11  19.0.1  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular           client
@angular-eslint/builder                  17.3.0   17.5.3  18.4.2  node_modules/@angular-eslint/builder                 client
@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin            17.3.0   17.5.3  18.4.2  node_modules/@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin           client
@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template   17.3.0   17.5.3  18.4.2  node_modules/@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template  client
@angular-eslint/schematics               17.3.0   17.5.3  18.4.2  node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics              client
@angular-eslint/template-parser          17.3.0   17.5.3  18.4.2  node_modules/@angular-eslint/template-parser         client
@angular/animations                      17.3.1  17.3.12  19.0.0  node_modules/@angular/animations                     client
@angular/cdk                             17.3.1  17.3.10  19.0.0  node_modules/@angular/cdk                            client
@angular/cli                             17.3.1  17.3.11  19.0.1  node_modules/@angular/cli                            client
@angular/common                          17.3.1  17.3.12  19.0.0  node_modules/@angular/common                         client
@angular/compiler                        17.3.1  17.3.12  19.0.0  node_modules/@angular/compiler                       client
@angular/compiler-cli                    17.3.1  17.3.12  19.0.0  node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli                   client
@angular/core                            17.3.1  17.3.12  19.0.0  node_modules/@angular/core                           client
@angular/fire                            17.0.1   17.1.0  18.0.1  node_modules/@angular/fire                           client
@angular/forms                           17.3.1  17.3.12  19.0.0  node_modules/@angular/forms                          client
@angular/language-service                17.3.1  17.3.12  19.0.0  node_modules/@angular/language-service               client
@angular/material                        17.3.1  17.3.10  19.0.0  node_modules/@angular/material                       client
@angular/platform-browser                17.3.1  17.3.12  19.0.0  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser               client
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic        17.3.1  17.3.12  19.0.0  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic       client
@angular/router                          17.3.1  17.3.12  19.0.0  node_modules/@angular/router                         client
@capacitor/android                        5.7.4    5.7.4   6.2.0  node_modules/@capacitor/android                      client
@capacitor/app                            5.0.7    5.0.7   6.0.2  node_modules/@capacitor/app                          client
@capacitor/cli                            5.7.4    5.7.4   6.2.0  node_modules/@capacitor/cli                          client
@capacitor/core                           5.7.4    5.7.4   6.2.0  node_modules/@capacitor/core                         client
@capacitor/haptics                        5.0.7    5.0.7   6.0.2  node_modules/@capacitor/haptics                      client
@capacitor/keyboard                       5.0.8    5.0.8   6.0.3  node_modules/@capacitor/keyboard                     client
@capacitor/status-bar                     5.0.7    5.0.7   6.0.2  node_modules/@capacitor/status-bar                   client
@ionic/angular                            7.8.1    7.8.6   8.4.0  node_modules/@ionic/angular                          client
@ionic/angular-toolkit                    9.0.0    9.0.0  12.1.1  node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit                  client
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin         6.21.0   6.21.0  8.15.0  node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin        client
@typescript-eslint/parser                6.21.0   6.21.0  8.15.0  node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser               client
chart.js                                  4.4.4    4.4.6   4.4.6  node_modules/chart.js                                client
core-js                                  3.36.1   3.39.0  3.39.0  node_modules/core-js                                 client
date-fns                                  3.6.0    3.6.0   4.1.0  node_modules/date-fns                                client
eslint                                   8.57.0   8.57.1  9.15.0  node_modules/eslint         
                         client
eslint-plugin-import                     2.29.1   2.31.0  2.31.0  node_modules/eslint-plugin-import                    client
eslint-plugin-jsdoc                      48.2.1  48.11.0  50.5.0  node_modules/eslint-plugin-jsdoc                     client
eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow                1.2.2    1.2.2   1.2.3  node_modules/eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow              client
firebase                                 10.9.0  10.14.1  11.0.2  node_modules/firebase                                client
ionicons                                  7.3.0    7.4.0   7.4.0  node_modules/ionicons                                client
jasmine-core                              5.1.2    5.1.2   5.4.0  node_modules/jasmine-core                            client
jasmine-spec-reporter                     5.0.2    5.0.2   7.0.0  node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter                   client
karma                                     6.4.3    6.4.4   6.4.4  node_modules/karma          
                         client
ngx-image-cropper                         8.1.0    8.1.1   9.0.0  node_modules/ngx-image-cropper                       client
tslib                                     2.6.2    2.8.1   2.8.1  node_modules/tslib          
                         client
typescript                                5.2.2    5.2.2   5.7.2  node_modules/typescript                              client
zone.js                                  0.14.4  0.14.10  0.15.0  node_modules/zone.js                                 client


i tried npm update as i read that it only updates safe packages, but it produces a bunch of errors on my project

So what is your goal? you have many issues. you just want to update the firebase packages? -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

not really, my main goal is to install the capacitor/push-notifications package but it needs certain version of the core, and when i try to install the core, it also needs specific versions of few packages

i am quite worried to update packages because i once got my project corrupted because updating incompatible packages
